# Generate A Unquie Id (GUID) That Is Only 25 Characters In Length

Tags: vb.net

What is the best appraoch to generate unquie ID's (no special characters) that will be 25 characters in length? I was thinking of generating a GUID and taking a substring of that, but I dont know if thats the best idea for uniqueness.

This is for dissconnected systems use. Creating a primary key in a database will not work in my situation. I need to create a unquie ID manually

I tried this but I am seeing duplicates in the output for some reason. So it doesnt seem too unquie even in this simple test..

```
 Sub Main()
        Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder
        For i As Integer = 1 To 100000
            Dim s As String = GenerateRandomString(25, True)
            sb.AppendLine(s)
            sb.AppendLine(Environment.NewLine)
        Next
        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Public Function GenerateRandomString(ByRef len As Integer, ByRef upper As Boolean) As String

        Dim rand As New Random()

        Dim allowableChars() As Char = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLOMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789".ToCharArray()

        Dim final As String = String.Empty

        For i As Integer = 0 To len - 1

            final += allowableChars(rand.Next(allowableChars.Length - 1))
        Next

        Return IIf(upper, final.ToUpper(), final)

    End Function
```

Comment: No, that's not a good idea.  Getting a unique ID is pretty simple, make it 1 more than the previous one.  Storing the previous one in a reliable way is something you'll have work on.  Any database knows how to do this.

Comment: Are we talking about generating this ID in seperate disconected physical locations?

Comment: yes Pat, I cannot simply generate the IDs from the database, they need to be generated manaully

Comment: Can you provide more context? You could have a singleton service available to you application which would allow the user to ask for some preallocated ids that you would store at the app end. The service does not have to be a db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re probably seeing duplicates because `New Random()` is seeded according to a system clock, which may not have changed by the next iteration.

Try a cryptographically secure RNG:

```
Const ALLOWABLE_ALL As String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
Const ALLOWABLE_UPPERCASE As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
Dim allowable As String = If(upper, ALLOWABLE_UPPERCASE, ALLOWABLE_ALL)
Dim result(len - 1) As Char
Dim current As Integer = 0

Using r As New Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider()
    Do
        Dim buffer(255) As Byte
        r.GetBytes(buffer)

        For b As Byte In buffer
            If b < allowable.Length Then
                result(current) = allowable(b)
                current += 1
                If current = len Then Return New String(result)
            End If
        Next
    Loop
End Using
```

This is also “more random” than your implementation in that letters aren’t weighted twice as heavily if `upper` is `True`.

Comment: @HansPassant: It’s very likely to be unique. Apart from that, no context except “I can’t use a primary key”. We’ve asked why…

Comment: Hmya, it is also very likely for a random number generator to generate the same number.  They have to, otherwise they are not random.  The difference is not that subtle.

Comment: @HansPassant: Cryptographically secure ones are not supposed to do that.

Comment: That just doesn't have anything to do with it.  It is cryptographically secure when the next number is very poorly correlated to the previous set of numbers.  That completely does not eliminate the odds for the same number.  It is *required* to be possible that the next number is the same to be cryptographically secure.  If that's eliminated then there's a correlation.  This is not subtle.

Comment: @HansPassant: Yes, and the odds for one 25-character, all-uppercase ID from this to collide with any of n distinct previous IDs should be in the realm of n in 200,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000.

Comment: Google "birthday paradox" to get a better estimate.

Comment: @HansPassant: The birthday attack on **MD5** is *barely* applicable; that’s one of the reasons it was not rejected as a cryptographic hash immediately. It has higher collision odds than this does.

Comment: @HansPassant: Although I did get that number wrong (25^36, not 36^25). MD5 is ~3e38 possibilities; 25 uppercase+digits is ~8e38. Google “birthday attack” for details on that one — I’d say it’s pretty safe.

Answer (score 1):

A GUID might be 32 digits, but only if expressed in hexadecimal. That means it will only use characters 0-9 and A-F. If your string can use the entire alphabet then you can express the same GUID in fewer characters, especially if your string can be case sensitive.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier#Text_encoding for an example of alternative encoding, or http://web.archive.org/web/20100408172352/http://prettycode.org/2009/11/12/short-guid/ for example code. EDIT: Or Hans's method above which is much better. If you want to encode a GUID with only A-Z, a-z and 0-9 characters then you will need to look up Base-62 encoding (as opposed to base-64) because you only have 62 characters to encode into.

Comment: Im not sure I follow you, can you share a sample?

Comment: The wording is wrong here, a GUID is 32 characters.  It doesn't matter if those chars are hex or ascii, it's still 32 chars (places).  The only thing that changes if it's ascii or hex is how many bits/bytes are used.

Comment: @TravisO: No, a GUID is a 128 bit number. It is commonly expressed as 32 hex characters but it does not have to be. It could be expressed as 128 0s and 1s, or as 32 hexadecimal characters, or as 22-24 ASCII characters.

Comment: To-may-toe to-mah-toe

Comment: @TravisO:   *Characters* is not an accurate measure of a GUID's length.  Every GUID i've seen has been represented by a string at least 36 characters long, due to the hyphens.  38 if you add braces, and upwards of 60 in C-struct format.  And that's just the ones i recognize as GUIDs; there are probably loads of stealth GUIDs out there.  (For example, the length of a MS product key -- 25 letters/digits + dashes -- is suspiciously close to 128 bits in size.)

Comment: When referring to GUIDs, you generally don't count the dashes, they're just there to make it more readable.  Hence why one says 32 chars but it occupies 36 spaces.  Products like MS SQL don't store 36 chars, even though you see the dashes, it actually stores a highly efficient HEX value and adds/removes the dashes when you're not looking.

Answer (score 0):

Stop trying to re-invent the wheel and just use .NET's built in GUID generator:

```
System.Guid.NewGuid()
```

which will generate a properly randomly seeded GUID, then simply sub-string it to your limit.  Even better if you grab the last 25 chars, instead of the first 25.

PS: I don't consider this a great idea in general, because it's the entire GUID that's considered unique, not part of it, but it should satisfy what you want.

Comment: No, that will not be guaranteed to be unique. A GUID is only guaranteed to be unique in its entirety and when generated according to a correct algorithm. By taking a substring you are getting rid of some of it. In practice it will probably work most of the time, but you have no guarantee of that.

Comment: @StephenHewlett if you read my post, you'll see that's exactly what I say in the PS, it's a bad idea.